# How can I describe the css grid container elements to deal with a dynamic number of columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

It is necessary, using only CSS, to describe the CSS grid elements in such a way that, depending on the size of the element, it occupies one or two columns. Those. if the content of an element is too wide, then it spans not one but two columns.

Example 1:
This is how the grid should behave if the content of all elements in the first column is less than 50% of the content of the container.
[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJe1g.png):

[image]

Example 2:
This is how the grid should look if the content of some element captures more than 50% of the infected content (It stretched to the full width, i.e. it occupied two columns of the grid. And, importantly, the neighboring element too).
[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvBBx.png):

[image]

P.S.
I'm not sure how this can be done without using JS, but if I calculate the width of already rendered elements using JS, then I will not be able to avoid unnecessary UI redraws (UI jumps).

I tried to combine different values of grid column settings with minmax etc. but eventually I realized that somehow the elements themselves need to be configured and I did not find any properties that could help me. It may be necessary to combine CSS GRID with CSS Flexbox somehow, but I don't quite understand how.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried and also describe how this query differs from the one that was answered yesterday at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76489450/how-can-i-set-range-of-css-grid-column-size

Comment: @AHaworth, I described at the end of the question what I tried to do. This question differs from yesterday's expected result. This case is much more complicated. (In the last question, I needed to achieve a different behavior of the elements, you can see this by reading both questions)

Comment: Not possible with Css-grid. Flexbox is probably an option in conjunction with max width but I suspect javascript is required